# grep() and sub() and regular expression

Tags: r, regex, string-substitution

I'd like to change the variable names in my `data.frame` from e.g. "pmm_StartTimev4_E2_C19_1" to "pmm_StartTimev4_E2_C19". So if the name **ends with an underscore followed by any number** it gets removed.

But I'd like for this to happen **only if** the variable name has the word "Start" in it.

I've got a muddled up bit of code that doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

```
# Current data frame:    
dfbefore <- data.frame(a=c("pmm_StartTimev4_E2_C19_1","pmm_StartTimev4_E2_E2_C1","delivery_C1_C12"),b=c("pmm_StartTo_v4_E2_C19_2","complete_E1_C12_1","pmm_StartTo_v4_E2_C19"))

# Desired data frame:
dfafter <- data.frame(a=c("pmm_StartTimev4_E2_C19","pmm_StartTimev4_E2_E2_C1","delivery_C1_C12"),b=c("pmm_StartTo_v4_E2_C19","complete_E1_C12_1","pmm_StartTo_v4_E2_C19"))

# Current code:
sub((.*{1,}[0-9]*).*","",grep("Start",names(df),value = TRUE)
```

Comment: `sub("_\\d$", ""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this using `gsub()`.

```
stripcol <- function(x) {
  gsub("(.*Start.*)_\\d+$", "\\1", as.character(x))  
}

dfnew <- dfbefore
dfnew[] <- lapply(dfbefore, stripcol)
```

We use the regular expression to look for "Start" and then grab everything but the underscore number at the end. We use `lapply` to apply the function to all columns.

Comment: There is only one substitution per string so `gsub` could be `sub`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` to capture groups where the 'Start' substring is also present followed by an underscore and one or more numbers.  In the replacement, use the backreference of the captured group.  As there are multiple columns, use `lapply` to loop over the columns, apply the `sub` and assign the output back to the original data

```
out <- dfbefore
out[] <- lapply(dfbefore, sub, 
            pattern = "^(.*_Start.*)_\\d+$", replacement ="\\1")
out

dfafter[] <- lapply(dfafter, as.character)
all.equal(out, dfafter, check.attributes = FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
doit <- function(x){
  x <- as.character(x)
  if(grepl("Start",x)){
    x <- gsub("_([0-9])","",x)
  }
  return(x)
} 


apply(dfbefore,c(1,2),doit)
```

> ```
>     a                          b                      
> [1,] "pmm_StartTimev4_E2_C19"   "pmm_StartTo_v4_E2_C19"
> [2,] "pmm_StartTimev4_E2_E2_C1" "complete_E1_C12_1"    
> [3,] "delivery_C1_C12"          "pmm_StartTo_v4_E2_C19"
> ```